# Using the setjmp and longjmp

Tags: c, setjmp

Having such a simple C code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>

void Com_Error(int);

jmp_buf abortframe;

int main() {
    
    if (setjmp (abortframe)){
        printf("abortframe!\n");
        return 0;           
    }
    
    Com_Error(0);
    
    printf("main end\n");    
    return 0;
}

void Com_Error(int code) {
    // ...
    longjmp (abortframe, code);
    //...
}
```

I'm getting:

> abortframe!

My question is WHY does it prints the `abortframe!` if we pass `0` (NOT `true`) and hence the condition `if (setjmp (abortframe)){...}` should NOT be meet so no `abortframe!` string printed?

Comment: You mustn't pass `0` in `longjmp`. See [man setjmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setjmp.3.html): *If the programmer mistakenly passes the value 0 in val, the "fake" return will instead return 1.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the friendly manual (C17 7.13.2.1):

> The longjmp function cannot cause the setjmp macro to return the value 0; if val is 0, the setjmp macro returns the value 1.